# Where is dmalloc in openSUSE?

Tags: opensuse

Which openSUSE rpm contains dmalloc? No repository have it. Tried to build it from src.rpm found for SLE 12. However it does not contain libdmalloc* libraries. How to do LD_PRELOAD="libdmalloc.so" ./my_program? Or it is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Works without LD_PRELOAD, seems not necessary any more, just simple:

1. eval `dmalloc -d 0 -l leak.log -p log-non-free`
2. ./my_program

However program should be built and linked with dmalloc:

```
#include <dmalloc.h>
```

Link:

> $ g++ -L/usr/lib64 -ldmalloc ...